# Oracle SQL - DISTINCT with count of supressed rows

Tags: sql, oracle, count, distinct, rownum

When I use the **DISTINCT** clause in sql, how can I add one last column with the **number of the rows that were "suppressed"** in just one (because they are equal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that directly with `distinct`. You could add an analytic `count()` in a subquery that then has `distinct` applied, but it's simpler to use an aggregate `count()` and a `group by` instead. You would have to include all the existing select-list items in the `group by` clause.

So if you had a table like this:

```
create table t42 (col1 number, col2 varchar2(10));
insert into t42 values (42, 'AAA');
insert into t42 values (42, 'AAA');
insert into t42 values (42, 'BBB');
insert into t42 values (42, 'BBB');
insert into t42 values (42, 'BBB');
insert into t42 values (43, 'AAA');
```

And you're currently doing this:

```
select distinct col1, col2
from t42
order by col1, col2;

      COL1 COL2     
---------- ----------
        42 AAA        
        42 BBB        
        43 AAA
```

To get the number of duplicates you can do:

```
select col1, col2, count(*)
from t42
group by col1, col2
order by col1, col2;

      COL1 COL2         COUNT(*)
---------- ---------- ----------
        42 AAA                 2 
        42 BBB                 3 
        43 AAA                 1
```

Comment: Thanks! It's more complex that what I was expecting, but works.